# apt --fix-broken install fails on unpack

Tags: apt, libreoffice

Today I tried to update my system (ubuntu 18.04) and got always this error with libreoffice:

```
andreas@ubuntu1804:apt$ sudo apt install console-setup
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Probieren Sie »apt --fix-broken install«, um dies zu korrigieren.
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 console-setup : Hängt ab von: keyboard-configuration (= 1.178ubuntu2.8) aber 1.178ubuntu2.7 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-base-core : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-calc : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-draw : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-gnome : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-gtk3 : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-impress : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-math : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-ogltrans : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 libreoffice-writer : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
 python3-uno : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 soll installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt --fix-broken install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).


andreas@ubuntu1804:apt$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Abhängigkeiten werden korrigiert ... Fertig
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden installiert:
  libreoffice-core
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
  libreoffice-core
1 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 14 nicht aktualisiert.
11 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 32,0 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 4.096 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] 
(Lese Datenbank ... 221464 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../libreoffice-core_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libreoffice-core (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) über (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-core_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 Link zur Sicherung von »./usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libooxlo.so« vor Installation der neuen Version kann nicht angelegt werden: Vorgang nicht zulässig
dpkg-deb: Fehler: Unterprozess einfügen wurde durch das Signal (Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)) getötet
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-core_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Already tried to purge the package, but it wants me first to fix-broken install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is a problem with libreoffice-core cached package, just remove it and fetch it again, the following commands will do it.

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-core_1%3a6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.5_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```